# Definite article in "Where applicable, the containers for parenteral preparations comply with the requirements..."

Tags: articles

From European Pharmacopoeia 8, Chapter 0520 "Parenteral Preparations"

> [image]

May we omit **the** here? I don't think that the previous mention of "containers for parenteral preparations" fully justifies the use of **the**, since it's not a particular set of containers.

Comment: In this document, does **are made** have the force of **are to be made**? Is the document describing items that meet a certain specification, so that there is an implicit "When they conform to this specification...." in front of every statement?

Comment: @TRomano - yes, "are to be made". This is a "general pharmacopoeial article" that lays down basic requirements for "parenteral preparations". A specific monograph for this or that drug may override some of these requirements.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use **the**. The second statement is a direct analogue of the first.  are made <-> comply; as far as possible <-> where applicable.

Comment: My take is that not all containers that are meant in the first paragraph, but only those (thence, "the"") capable of being applied where they are to be/are being applied.

Comment: @TRomano - that's odd. I thought that European Pharmacopoeia is proofread by native speakers of English. A, "where applicable" changes the meaning? Now I see.

Comment: @Rompey: the containers aren't being applied.  "Where applicable" means "Where necessary" or "As may be required by the situation".

Comment: @CowperKettle: "Where applicable" would not call for the article.  *Cakes are to be made without tree nuts. Where applicable, cakes are to comply with  paragraph 5.1 relating to Genetically Modified Organisms*.

Comment: That first paragraph makes little sense to me.  Are the preparations made from transparent materials or not?  If so "as far as possible" seems to mean the opposite -- I would expect "as much as possible".  Also "containers ... comply" is awkward.  "Should comply" or "must comply" makes more sense to me.

Comment: "as far as possible" = "as much as possible".  *to the extent possible*.

Comment: @TRomano I get that but it's confusing at first read since it could also imply "as far away as possible".  Seems an awkward turn of phrase.

Comment: @Andrew : Think of it as a variant of "insofar as possible". https://www.google.com/search?q=%22insofar%20as%20possible%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: This selection of text looks like legalese, which is a variation or sub-dialect of common English. Lawyers have created a variation on common English grammar which they understand among themselves, but normal English speakers may not always agree with. With legalese, the final arbitrar of what is correct legalese grammar is always the Judge (who is usually also a lawyer) that presides during the court case that is being brought relating to the legal text. Legalese, like other jargons, also has words that have specific meaning for lawyers that doesn't match common English meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EUROPEAN PHARMACOPOEIA 6.0- 2008 3.1 Materials used for the Manufacture of containers 3.1
>
> 3 . 1 . 3 Polyolefines 3 . 1 . 4 Polyethylene without additives for Containers for preparations for Parenteral and for Ophthalmic Preparations 3 . 1 . 5.Polyethylene with additives for Containers for preparations for Parenteral and for Ophthalmic Preparations 3 . 1 . 6 Polypropylene for Containers and Closures for Parenteral and Ophthalmic Preparations 3 . 1 . 7 Poly(ethylene – vinylacetate) for Containers and Tubing for total Parenteral Nutrition Preparations ..

It would seem there is a  great deal of information needed to determine if ""*containers for parenteral preparations*" might meet the materials requirements.
As the entire range of "*containers for parenteral preparations*", or other containers not described, cannot be known from the available information, one must believe the  "the" is required  as a description to assure those containers comply with general container regulations.
A more positive determination can only be had with all the pertinent information at hand.